# Centering an image in a paragraph

Tags: css-float, css

I am looking for a purely CSS way to center an image within a paragraph of text so the text wraps on both sides of the image.

```
Ideely the image  |-----| would be placed
before or after   |-img-| the text within
the code structure|-----| and the text 
would wrap around the image.
```

Comment: This is somewhat difficult to do. Which browsers do you need to support? IE7? IE8? Does the image always have the same dimensions? Does the text change?

Comment: The image properties are set and the text is likely to change. Browser support is not an issue, but HTML5 and CSS3 cannot be used.

Comment: `Browser support is not an issue, but HTML5 and CSS3 cannot be used.` - that doesn't really tell me anything useful. What *browsers/versions* would I have to test my potential answer in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer that works quite well available at: 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/

Answer (score 2):

IE10 Platform Preview supposedly (according to [this article](http://www.netmagazine.com/features/future-css-layouts)) has a new feature called **positioned floats** that seem to accomplish what you're looking for.

For now, though, I think you're screwed :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible:

```
<p> Text that goes here and image <img src="img.jpg"/> continues text</p>
```

As far as I know browsers treat `<p>`content as belonging to a line, thus when the browser parses your p-tag which contains the image it will automatically make that line as high as the image.

Maybe it's possible with css3 though...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this. I have looked far and wide.

The other answers here don't address the question as it is asked. [This link](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/) (A List Apart) requires the use of two paragraphs of text, and you can't do it dynamically because you have to be careful to match up the text on both sides of the image.

The other, IE10's positioned floats (Microsoft calls them [exclusions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh673558.aspx)), does sort of work, but with a list of caveats:

- It's IE-only.
- You have to specify things like the number of columns, rather than an offset.
- It doesn't work well when the window is resized. Other content gets overlapped, and the container maintains a minimum size.