# text wrap around centered image in paragraph

Tags: html, css

For example:

```
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text ------------------- text text text text 
text text text text |this is the image| text text text text
text text text text ------------------- text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Look for an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017465/centering-an-image-in-a-paragraph

Comment: i found this http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/ website too. is quite useful but i am looking in a single image within a single paragraph instead of 2 or more.

Comment: Put image and text on canvas

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article using pseudo elements.

http://css-tricks.com/float-center/

Comment: this link-only answer will work if you want to use multiple columns (or rather, multiple div's as pseudo-columns).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible ...

```html
<p style="font: 12px Arial, sans-serif; width: 300px;">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet nunc a neque vehicula mollis. Sed ac augue a purus

    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

    congue aliquet vitae id libero. Aenean porttitor &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ultricies neque. Cras lorem nulla, rhoncus &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; id est at, luctus mattis magna. Sed imperdiet &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    vel risus id luctus. Donec efficitur ar &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; pharetra. Donec tincidunt ligula magna, &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; et gravida orci lacinia quis. In semper congue nisl, a &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; pretium augue euismod et. Suspendisse felis nibh, feugiat vel mollis eu, dapibus tempus arcu. Etiam porttitor tortor nec gravida semper. Morbi metus lorem, volutpat ac varius

    <img  style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:90px; width:100px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
    
</p>
```

1. Make a paragraph `p` with a fixed font size and fixed width.
2. Make an image `img` positioned absolute.
3. Put non breaking spaces `&nbsp;` where the image overlay.

Comment: sure, if you know *exactly* how all attributes of the element/font/image/page will render on any platform/device/browser that it will ever be opened on.  (This is basically the exact opposite of "responsive design".)   :-)

Comment: Unresponsible design? ;) ... the width has to be fixed too and px used everywhere. Use monospace font.