# Text floating around a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make text flowing around the image, in a different scenario. the image wont be inside the content. Image would be a seperate component and the div with text will be a seperate component. So markup will look like this

```
<img class="imgtofloat" src="images/1.png" alt="" />
<div class="divwithcontent">
 <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

The scenario is that we cant change the markup but we need to position the image between the content and make the content float around it.

**EDIT 1:**
**I need the image to be in the center of the content as it is in this image https://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/14477076543/**

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html check this link you will get the answer

Comment: related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017465/centering-an-image-in-a-paragraph

Comment: I'm 99.9% positive this can't be done without changing the markup. There's no way to move the image and have the text float around the top, as a margin/padding would be in the way. To do this you'd need to put the `img` tag inside the `p` tag.

Comment: You can use a column structure, specify three columns and put the image in the middle one

Answer (score 1):

We can stretch our CSS imagination. Hide the image and replace it with background.

Example, possibly adaptable.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/d34Nz/2/)

CSS

```
img {
    display: none;
}
p:first-child:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/100) no-repeat;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I need the image to be in the vertically center of the content as it is in this image https://www.flickr.com/photos/41695354@N08/14477076543/

Comment: Edited my answer. This is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can Change the image placement. 
step 1) put image in between the paragraph text.
step 2) and one attribute in img tag align="left"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inline style, if you just have a few CSS rules.

```
<img src="images/1.png" alt="" style="float: left" />
```