# Place image in center of two columns

Tags: html, css, image, center, shapes

I'm developing a WordPress Theme with Twitter Bootstrap.
The goal is to have a two column page layout with a centered image, where the text floats around this round image.

My approach with the pseude elements comes from this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/float-center/. The problem is, that I am not able to center the pseude elements vertically.

During my research I also found this thread [Centering an image in a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017465/centering-an-image-in-a-paragraph) but I am not sure if I can use this, because the text (which in my case will come from wordpress) is interrupted by a span --> not user friendly.

CSS:

```
.picture { position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -100px; height:200px;}

    .text-left, .text-right { width: 49%; text-align: justify;}
    .text-left { float: left; }
    .text-right { float: right; }

    .text-left:before, .text-right:before { content: ""; top:200px; width: 100px; height: 200px; }

    .text-left:before { float: right; shape-outside: circle(50%); top:20%;}
    .text-right:before { float: left; shape-outside: circle(50%); top:20%;}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <br><br><br>

   <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/ksdpa4em9/rund.png" alt="Image" class="picture">
    <div class="text-left">
    <p class="lead element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="text-right">
    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLodr7n3/

Comment: I can't see the problem from your fiddle link...

Comment: I am not able to center the image vertically. It should be in middle of the page

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean by your statement "...the text (which in my case will come from wordpress) is interrupted by a span --> not user friendly..."? Is that the exact end content that will be populating the page? Secondly, is the shape going to be consistently part of the layout, and will it always be a CSS-generated circle (will it be an image or something that will change from page to page)? Thirdly, is this going to be a responsive design?

Comment: There will be a different round image on every page, but it will have the same size.

Comment: cant edit my previously comment: First: Yes, the endcontent will be populated from the wordpress editor. I don't want to include any hacks there. Secons: There will be a different round image on every page, but it will allways have the same size. Third: Yes, it is going to be responsive, but on mobile i don't want to show the image

Answer (score 0):

I think without adding the necessary html elements as outlined in this example:

https://alistapart.com/article/crosscolumn

I don't believe it is possible.