# I am trying to wrap text around a centered image in CSS separating this into two columns. Has anyone been able to find responsive solution for this?

Tags: html, css

Placing text close to the edges of an image is pretty easy if you're just aligning that image in the very left or right of the screen. You can usually just use float: left/ right or use flex with specified margins. But what if you need that image right in the center with text wrapped around it? This seems like a simple and very common request but I have yet to find a solid answer.

To demonstrate, you can do this type of text wrapping in a Word document. The text automatically adjusts into two columns on each side of the image.

However, I have navigated the deepest corners of the web to try and find an answer for how to do this with modern HTML & CSS. Most of what I've been able to find is pretty outdated and doesn't use very responsive strategies. For example, [this](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Ebnelson/computer/css/wrappingtextaroundimages.html) article suggests it's a good idea to use the <align> tag despite it being deprecated. Closest answer I've been able to get is to use some form of [pseudo-code](https://css-tricks.com/float-center/) to essentially trick CSS into creating a gap between two columns of text. I'm curious to know if anyone has found a faster, much more responsive solution, as it seems this has mysteriously been left unsolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017465/centering-an-image-in-a-paragraph

Comment: Interesting.  I thought the align attribute for the img tag did this without any CSS.  I tried it and "left" and "right" work, but not "center".  I'm curious about a real answer to this question too, though I've never wanted the image centered instead of left or right aligned.